# SVN TORTOISE backup on any computers

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Have any question:
Where SVN default path on hard disc?
How to backup svn on any computer in lan?

You should install Windows on your computer and we need to not destroy data
We use the svn server čolabnet ....
Hoe to do this?
PLEASE PLEASE HELP TO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to the user settings, they reside in %APPDATA%/Subversion, but those are not very important, the most important data that is stored there are the passwords for the repositories, and you can just type them in again if you loose your password file.

If you refer to the svn-sandbox (the checkout directory), you can just copy it anywhere you want and you will still be able to access it.

If you refer to the server-side svn-repository itself, you should use the command `svnadmin hotcopy` to clone the repository.

Comment: thanks.where repository is store?

Comment: there is no standard location. it's stored where you created it :)

Comment: how copy svn server in any computers?

Comment: copy full svn hosry...all version alll repository...????

Comment: we use collabnet SVN,and we can move all repository and data in order omputer,becose reinstal win....ho to please help me...???